# How to translate runic text not knowing the origin?

Tags: norse-mythology

I found a runic text (See chapter two of [Jules Verne's Journey to the Center of the Earth](https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/sffaudio-usa/pictures/images13/page_444.jpeg)) and I want to translate it, but can't find the symbols in any charts of any bigger runic language.

What is the easiest way to decipher it?

[image: runic text]

Comment: If you don't know the origin, why do you want to translate it? Without my Futhark handy, I'm guessing it's not in Norse at all.

Comment: Is this a historical text?  There isn't enough information to conclude that it is text, rather than artwork.  History relies on sources, context and citations. Can you tell us where you found this, in what context, or any other details?

Comment: It's from chapter two of Jules Verne's _Journey to the Center of the Earth_.  See https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/is-a-runic-manuscript-of-the-heimskringla-realistic

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It's from a famous fictional work by Jules Vernes. Without edits, I'd say, "the easiest way to decipher it"  would be to read [Chapter 3 of Journey to the Center of The Earth?](https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/sffaudio-usa/pictures/images13/page_444.jpeg) [As such](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Journey_to_the_Center_of_the_Earth_%28Chapter_III_runes%29.svg) I'm tempted to suggest this is perhaps better suited elsewhere, on CryptographySE?

Comment: @kimchilover Indeed, and it calls them Icelandic runes, though the orthography of some of these is unusual.

Comment: From a work of fiction, I'm highly doubtful that it has a translation; I suspect it is artwork. This suspicion is reinforced by the discussion that KimchiLover found on [mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/is-a-runic-manuscript-of-the-heimskringla-realistic), the serifs and the regular orthography.  Verne was not, to my knowledge, known for verisimilitude.

Comment: In a search for a scholarly article about this, I ran across https://www.prc68.com/I/pdf/SCB108JVMF.pdf .

Comment: I'd recommend that @kimchilover post that as an answer.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It does in fact have a "translation" provided right in Verne's text (Arne Saknussemm), and it does kind of align with existing runes, but without Verne explicitly saying what the translation is it would probably be impossible to come up with a definitive answer.

Comment: In any case, I think it should be off topic here as I don't think we should be about providing translations of fictional scripts (even if based on real ones).

Comment: I'm with @called2voyage here.  In fact, I voted to close this question, so it'd seem churlish to also post an answer.

Comment: I will abstain on the close vote - but I will note that you found both a positive answer and demonstrated historical research methods. Yes, the subject is anhistorical, but the process was valid (and exceeded my research).  And to be fair, the question asked *how*.  I think your answer exceeded expectations.  Thanks for amusing my afternoon.

Comment: @kimchilover Compared to real runes (in this case Icelandic), these are just off in too many ways. As is the name itself. As a nice play on dirty words though… It is intended to be a presentation of a puzzle solved, in Alfred's words a McGuffin. And quite far from the level of Tolkien's works at the methodology level.

Comment: @kimchilover it was indeed from the book, thank you for pointing it.

Comment: There is a nice book by Maurice Pope on the general subject:  [_The Story of Decipherment_](https://www.amazon.com/Story-Decipherment-Egyptian-Hieroglyphs-Script/dp/050028105X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It reads "*Arne Saknussem*", just as the text states.

Easiest cipher ever to decode.

[image]

I first solved this when I was nine or ten.

Note that one third of the English alphabet, 8 letters (AEKMNRSU), including three of the five vowels (AEU), are in that one short inscription. It would not take much more to fully decipher more complex text. Think "*Wheel of Fortune*".

[image]

[This turns up on a Google search](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-61576.html) which fills in much of the remaining alphabet:

```
A B C D E F   G H I J K L

M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W
```

[image]

Comment: ᛆᚱᚿᛂ ᛋᛆᚴᚿᚿᛋᛋᛂᛘᛘ / ᛋᚴᚮᛟᛐᚿᚿ?

Comment: Technically, the question asks *how* to solve, not *what does it say*... but that is a quodlibet.

Comment: ℑ                 ,     '                      ‎

Comment: @PieterGeerkens,  Nice +1,   Impressed that we got a science fiction alchemist reference passed our sensors.   I recently brought a hoodie for my nine year old back from Iceland with Runes on it and she was able to translate all of them.   I was going to get her to take a crack at this..  Coarse she has the internet and google images to assist her.

Comment: @LаngLаngС: Is that the identical alphabet? The font is very small, and my eyesight not the same since my cataract surgery, but it seems to have non-canon runes for Verne's story.

Comment: It is what made it into [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runic_(Unicode_block)). As such I am quite doubtful that what looks like meant to be a ligature for double m  is really more [Tvimadur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendehorn), leading me on that char alone that Vernes conflates here *Binde-* and *Sturzrune* for Madr or Marcomannic Gilch? Also the R as yr-rune (which would have an Icelandic specialty form)? Given the timeframe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_runes should come closest to what JV wanted?